# ¿Por qué mi código de PHPmailer no me toma los valores de mi formulario?

Tags: formularios, phpmailer

Soy nueva con el tema de Front End y no tengo mucha idea de PHP ( aunque me doy maña). Hice mi página de porfolio pero tengo problemas con mi formulario.

El phpmailer me envía los correos sin los datos del formulario.

Esto es lo que recibo en el mail:

> Haz recibido un mensaje
>
> Nombre:
>
> Correo:
>
> Comentarios:

Copio mi código a continuación:

```
<?php

include("../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
include("../PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
include("../PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$comentarios = $_POST['texto'];

$body = "Haz recibido un mensaje <br/> <br/>
<strong>Nombre: </strong>" . $nombre ."<br/><br/><strong>Correo:</strong>" . $email ."<br/><br/><strong>Comentarios:</strong>" .$comentarios;

try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Username = 'contacto@veritoweb.com.ar';
    $mail->Password = '***********';

    $mail->setFrom('contacto@veritoweb.com.ar', 'ConctactoWeb');
    $mail->addAddress('mimail@gmail.com', 'Vero');   

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Formulario de Contacto';
    $mail->Body = $body; 

    if(!$mail->send()){
        error_log('Lo siento, algo NO salió muy bien. Por favor intente nuevamente!.');
    } else {
        echo 'Mensaje enviado! Me pondré en contacto a la brevedad.';
        echo $nombre;
        header("refresh:5;http://veritoweb.com.ar");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
?>
```

Comment: Que error estás recibiendo en el error.log?

Comment: ninguno! por que el correo me llega... en teoría el problema está que no captura los inputs..

Comment: Entonces, deberías mostrarnos el código de tu formulario, ¿no? Entretanto, prueba en PHP con un `echo print_r($_GET);` o `echo print_r($_POST)` a ver qué estás enviando realmente...

Comment: Modifica el "Haz" por "Has", te entenderan mejor. Luego explicanos como estas ejecutando ese archivo PHP, porque si lo haces directamente no hay datos POST, lo debes llamar desde un formulario que en su elemento <form> su atributo **method** ponga **POST** y en su atributo **action** apunte a este archivo PHP, y dentro de los campos **input** del formulario coincidan sus atributos **name=** con las claves POST esperadas.

Comment: @DavidJP, gracias por tu respuesta, me sale lo sig:  array ( [nombre] => [mail] => [texto]) 1Mensaje enviado! me pondre en contacto a la brevedad,

Comment: @masterguru, gracias por tu respuesta y tu corrección jajajajaj ya lo cambie!! ya agrego el codigo del form, pero lo tengo asi como me decis!!

Comment: `<form id="formulario" class="formulario" action="php/form.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required>`

Comment: La línea donde estas instanciando a la clase PHPMailer: ```$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();``` no está bien, la cambiaria por ```$mail = new PHPMailer(true);```, luego también puedes comprobar si estas obteniendo los datos por POST, haciendo un ```var_dump($_POST);``` en la primera línea. Tienes un ejemplo como usarlo aqui: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @DBE, gracias por tu respueta, lo cambie y no me funciono! me sale este error: Array ( [nombre] => [mail] => [texto] => )
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in ***/php/form.php:22 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **** on line 22

Comment: ¿Eso quiere decir que no encuentra tu clase PHPMailer, estas seguro que la ruta es la correcta? ```include ../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php```

Comment: @DBE, no lo creo ya que lo cambio y el mensaje es otro! me tira otro mensaje: Array ( [nombre] => [mail] => [texto] => ) Mensaje enviado! Me pondré en contacto a la brevedad.   y el mail me llega!!!

Comment: @Vero, he estado haciendo pruebas en tu web y he visto que tienes a la escucha el evento **submit** en javascript, donde haces esto: `inputs.forEach(i=>{ i.value='';` y seguramente es el problema en si, pues parece ejecutarse **antes** de realizar el envio de los datos, dejándolos vacios. Quita eso y espero que te funcione bien.  En todo caso, prueba con `formulario.reset();` para limpiar los campos, a ver si con eso evitas dejar los inputs vacios antes de enviarlos.

Comment: @masterguru me solucionaste la vida!!!!! era eso... (aunque el forumulario.reset no me funciona) pero por lo menos ya recibo los mails correctamente!! con la practica se aprende , Te super agradezco!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado. La próxima vez piensa en si también estas usando javascript, como en este caso, para incluirlo en la pregunta, sino nos volvemos locos porque no tenia sentido que no te funcionara con la información que nos habias dado. Saludos!